# How can I make Arrow fountains using spawners?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a map with arrow lasers you know that kind of thing... Just I can't seem to make the arrows spray in one direction. They randomly spawn.

Is there a command that changes that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking how to shoot arrows in a specified direction. Use the Motion tag, like this:
`/summon Arrow ~ ~ ~ {Motion:[1.2,4.5,3.2]}`
But you can replace the numbers with your own values. The order is X,Y,Z. So `/summon Arrow ~ ~ ~ {Motion:[0.0,10.0,0.0]}` will make the arrow shoot up. And `/summon Arrow ~ ~ ~ {Motion:[10.0,0.0,0.0]}` will make the arrow shoot across the X axis, with a velocity of 10. You can play around with these values. 
*Note:* The values must all have a decimal, even if there are no numbers beyond the whole number.